# BFS in python from a preorder and inorder

Tags: python, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

(Python 2.7)I need to print the bfs of a binary tree with a given preorder and inorder and a max lenght of the strings of preorder and inorder. 
I know how it works, for example:
preorder:ABCDE
inorder:CBDAE
max length:5

```
                A
             /     \
           B        E
          / \         
         C   D
```

BFS:ABECD

So far I got this figured out

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__ (self, value, parent=None):
            self.parent = parent
            self.left_child = None
            self.right_child = None
            self.value=value

    def setLeftChild(self, child=None):
            self.left_child = child
            if child:
                child.parent = self

    def setRightChild(self, child=None):
            self.right_child = child
            if child:
                child.parent = self


preorder={}
inorder={}

print "max string length?"
i=int(raw_input())
count=0
while i>count:
    print"insert the preorder"
    preorder[raw_input()]=count
    count=count+1
print "preorder is",sorted(preorder, key=preorder.get)

count2=0
while i>count2:
    print"insert the inorder"
    inorder[raw_input()]=count2
    count2=count2+1
print "inorder is",sorted(inorder, key=inorder.get)
root=
```

I've figured out how to create a binary tree in python but the thing is I don't know how to add the values of the next childs. As you can see I already have the root and figured out how to insert the first childs (left and right) but I don't know how to add the next ones.

Answer (score 2):

I guess essentially the question is how to get all the parent-leftChild pairs and parent-rightChild pairs of the tree from given preorder and inorder

To get the parent-leftChild pairs, you need to check: 1) if node1 is right after node2 in preorder; 2) if node2 is in front of node1 in inorder

For your example preorder:ABCDE inorder:CBDAE

- B is right after A in preorder and B is in front of A in inorder, thus B is the left child of A.
- D is right after C in preorder, but D is also after C in inorder, thus D is not the left child of C

You can use the similar trick to get all parent-rightChild pairs

Comment: So I should do a "if" for example, to determine where the node goes based on the preorder and inorder input i'm given? the thing is that the preorder and inorder length can be bigger than 5 and that's were i'm getting a little bit confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomásMedina yes, and you should get all pairs like A-B, B-C, C-D... in the preorder list, and validate them in the inorder list. So it doesn't matter how long the preorder lists is, you need to go through it anyway

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm on the right track but what do you mean with getting all the pairs? I didn't understand that part.
I was thinking in comparing the position of the elements between the two lists and from that decide where they go. Is this ok or do you think there's a more simple or efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @TomásMedina I mean for A and B on the preorder list, you check them on the inorder list to see if B appear earlier than A, if yes, it means B is the left child of A. You do the same check for the orther pairs on the preorder list, which are B and C, C and D, D and E. Sorry if the word "pair" confuses you, but hope you get my point

Comment: Oh, that was exactly what I wanted to do, looks like we were both talking about the same thing but on a different way. But know how can I compare the positions between the two lists? Thanks a lot for your help man.

Comment: I just edited the code, now i'm using dictionary since i figured out is easier to use it since it already gives me values for each position

Answer (score 1):

To add children to any node, just get the node that you want to add children to and call setLeftChild or setRightChild on it.

Comment: like root.left_child.setLeftChild(BinaryTree(preorder[2])) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BFS - you ideally want to be using a graph - an excellent library is [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html)

An example:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge('A', 'B')
g.add_edge('A', 'E')
g.add_edge('B', 'C')
g.add_edge('B', 'D')

print 'A' + ''.join(node[1] for node in (nx.bfs_edges(g, 'A')))

# ABECD
```